# WiFi problem after upgrade

Tags: wifi

after making all the updates after the first installation and restarting the system, I can no longer activate the wifi or rather I can activate / deactivate it but in the settings screen it always tells me that it is deactivated.
I have a Matebook d14 2020 with Ryzen 7, how can I fix?
I attach a image of the error/bug[image]

Comment: This problem is part of my own. Wired connection seems connected (even the LED on router glows) but internet doesn't work. And trying to connect via wireless doesn't show any hotspots. Also sometimes random blank window pops up with shield with exclamation mark in the header. What now?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I found the solution myself.

Apparently the problem is due to the Realtek 8822c video card driver (which is missing the rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin file needed to correctly load the rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin driver)

The solution is to download the latest version of linux-firmware from:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/snapshot/linux-firmware-20200918.tar.gz

Extract and copy the contents of the rtw88 folder to /lib/firmware/rtw88

Restart the operating system.

When restarting the wifi card will be fully functional!